# Duplicate key violation occuring even with EntityState set

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor

I am trying to update the values of a project item, specifically the assigned users to the project. The feature is to be able to remove users from an already created project via an edit button. In the function below I am finding the relevant project using a passed in projectID and then finding all users associated to the project. From there I am finding the specific users from the group of users associated to the project which I am looking to remove. Finally the user is removed using the List .Remove() method. (The company value is also found `companyFind` and assigned to its relevant value)

The `AssignedUsersToProject` will now only contain users who should be associated to the project once .Remove() is changed. I have looped through and set them to have an `Unchanged` state, the same goes for the company.

However when saving in the database to update the record the following error is shown despite the use of Unchanged

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ApplicationUserProject'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ApplicationUserProject'. The duplicate key value is (5685a830-cb82-4b60-b459-c0852cc74563, 229698cd-eebb-432b-e6eb-08d9b62cc799).
The statement has been terminated.
```

How could I prevent this from occuring? I thought unchanged would stop the record from being re-inserted into the database on update. Would appreciate any insight into this. Thanks in advance

### Project Model

```
public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

        public Guid companyID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ProjectName { get; set; } 

        public ICollection<ApplicationUser> AssignedUsersToProject { get; set; }

        public Company assignedCompanyForProject { get; set; }
    }
```

### ApplicationUser model

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller function

```
    [HttpPut("removeUser/{username}/{projectID}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveUserFromProject(string username, Guid projectID)
    {

        var project = await _context.Projects.FindAsync(projectID);
        var query = _context.Users.Where(u => u.Projects.Any(p => p.ProjectId.ToString().Equals(project.ProjectId.ToString()))); //find all users for the project
        var companyFind = _context.Companies.First(c => c.CompanyId.ToString().Equals(project.companyID.ToString())); //companyID to current projects company ID

        //_context.Attach(project);
        project.AssignedUsersToProject = query.ToList();
        project.assignedCompanyForProject = companyFind;

        var removeUser = query.First(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));
        project.AssignedUsersToProject.Remove(removeUser);

        foreach (var x in project.AssignedUsersToProject)
        {
            _context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }

        _context.Entry(project.AssignedUsersToProject).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        _context.Entry(project.assignedCompanyForProject).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return NoContent();
    }
```

### Edit

Suggested changes

```
[HttpPut("removeUser/{username}/{projectID}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveUserFromProject(string username, Guid projectID)
{

var project = _context.Projects.Include(u => u.AssignedUsersToProject).FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProjectId.ToString().Equals(projectID.ToString()));

// remove user where username is match
project.AssignedUsersToProject.Remove(project.AssignedUsersToProject.First(u => u.UserName == username));

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the error you're getting, but I think your solution here is overly complex for what you're trying to achieve. For example, it's unclear why you need to be worrying about the company at all, as it is not relevant to removing users from the project. Also, in general you shouldn't need to worry about manipulating EntityState very often with Entity Framework, as the state is managed for you.

Comment: I thought the company being null might be causing some error so I found the company just to make sure it's not the issue. I have left it in the post to assure that it was not causing an issue.

Comment: I'd probably try to simplify first, rather than add more complexity.
All you should need is something like:
1) Find the project (the same as you have)
2) Find the matching user within project.AssignedUsersToProject (assuming you have lazy loading enabled, the assigned users will be loaded from the database automatically for you when you iterate through the collection)
3) Remove that user from project.AssignedUsersToProject
4) _context.SaveChangesAsync()

Comment: If that doesn't work, you may have a problem with either your mappings, or the constraints in your database.

Comment: This is what I have done but when trying to `SaveChangesAsync()` It ends up trying to re-save the remaining users within  `AssignedUsersToProject` which is causing duplication keys but I have set the state to `Unchanged` and so I am unsure why this is occurring

Comment: Hmm I see... yes, under normal circumstances that shouldn't occur and you shouldn't need to set the State to Unchanged or anything. Sorry, I'm not sure what would be causing that. Maybe post your classes and mappings too in your question, in case there is a problem with them.

Comment: Updated the post to show the ApplicationUser model class as well

Comment: Yes, you're doing way too much here, partly because you don't understand EF. If a navigation property is `null` (`project.assignedCompanyForProject`) it only means it's not loaded, i.e. `Include`-ed in the query or lazy loaded. In this case it's not necessary at all to load it, let alone to set it. Likewise, `project.AssignedUsersToProject` isn't populated because you didn't `Include` it.

Comment: ... Just `Include` it when pulling `project` from the database (you'd need a `FirstOrDefault()` then instead of `Find()`) and remove all code involved with setting navigation properties and state changes. Just do `project.AssignedUsersToProject.Remove(removeUser);` and save changes.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited the post above and shown how I understood your implementation. Would this be correct? Also If I wanted to add a user would the process be somewhat similar except I would do `.Add()` instead of `.Remove()`?

Comment: Looks OK, but only you can tell if it actually works. And yes, you can just add a user. It's largely what the duplicate says on your other question on the same topic.

Comment: I have tested it and it seems to work, huge thanks for this! If you post the above as an answer I can accept it

Comment: Which EF version are you in?

Comment: @Krellex. An observation (perhaps unwelcome) -  You have posted a significant number of questions on EF and issues you are having with building complex relationships between EF entities.  It would seem to me that in  "Clean" Design principles you are trying to build your core application logic into your data layer.  Personally I keep my data layer simple, I build the relationships into my "Core" application objects.  My `DboProject` just gets the project entity data.  My `CdoProject` - Cdo = Core Data Object - contains the assigned users.

Comment: Which EF version? I don't mind adding an answer but I need the exact EF version for it. In general, it's always useful to tack the appropriate version tag to questions.